# Is this a better way to limit global vars?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I hear **limit your global variables** i javascript.

If I **have to** declare variables in global scope then I will do something like this:

```
var global1 = 0, global2 = 1, global3 = 2, global4 = 3;
```

Here I have four global variables. Now I thought of limiting the numbers of global variables and did some thing like this

```
var globals = {
    global1 : 0,
    global2 : 1,
    global3 : 2,
    global4 : 3
}
```

I wanted to know whether the second method is better or just the same, since by exposing the variable **globals** I am exposing the other others also.

Comment: Once you have a good idea of namespacing is, check this out. It will definitely help. http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

Comment: Thanx, I read the article at your link. It mainly says that name spacing avoids collisions and I think its good. But is there any performance related issue with these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is basically called namespacing and is done by most big libraries like, e.g., jQuery uses `jQuery` and/or `$` to hold all of its variables and functions.

The main reason for reducing the amount of global vars is to limit possible collisions, if different scripts use the same variable names.

So, e.g., script A defines a global variable `cache` for its internal purposes. When now a second, unrelated script B needs another global variable of that name, you will run into trouble as probably script B will just overwrite the variable of script A.

By putting your variables (and functions as well) into a global namespace of your own with a name that probably is not used by any other script, you reduce the probability of the aforementioned to happen.

Comment: Ok, other than avoiding name collisions is there any performance advantage of it?

Comment: @DigvijayYadav If you're not excessively using global variables, I see no real performance impact of either solution (unless you want to do massive calculations that is).

Answer (score 0):

Second method is named namespace and it is better.

```
var mynamespace = mynamespace || {};
```

Then you get object if it exist or create a new one.